# How to import java module in Kotlin Gradle script

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I would like to import `java.lang.module` to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html

How can I do this in a gradle `.kts` Kotlin script?

I tried

```kotlin
import java.lang.module
```

which did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import packages in Java. You need to import a specific class:

```
import java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor
```

Or import all classes from a package:

```
import java.lang.module.*
```

It is not really related to Gradle, it is specific to Java/Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Project JDK to JDK 11. Import the Version class directly.